# SQL Query for fetching the data of users not submitting their time for a particular week?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables one containing user information and the other having their time entered for the weeks as below!

```
Table1
------
UserID (PK)
Username
Email
Phone


Table2
------
Timesheetid (PK)
UserID (FK)
Weekenddate(date)
Totaltimeworked
```

From the above tables I want to retrieving the user ID,username and email from TABLE 1 for the user who have not entered information in the table 2 based on the weekend date(weekend date is selected in the search field and not hardcoded).

Please help me with the SQL query to create this table .

Comment: do you have a date_table in your database?

Comment: As a general rule, @gokul, we like to see some attempt at solving the problem.  Even if your code doesn't work, it shows that you've tried.  You can edit your question and give us more information.

Comment: i have edited the question ! could you please help for the query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this working code on **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20237/3)**. As you haven't posted any data and columns definition I assume `weekenddate` to be a varchar.

On the condition `Weekenddate = 'sunday' OR Weekenddate = 'saturday'` substitute the values *sunday* and *saturday* by your parameter value. In fact, you will only need to use on of the clauses of the condition as you have only one parameter with the weekend value. Then just wrap the code into an

```
`INSERT INTO your_new_table (UserID, Username)`
```

Comment: weekend date is a date field. and i want the username and ID from table 1 who ever dint submit the time in table 2 for selected weekend date from search in a new table

Answer (score 0):

Considering your Totaltimeworked column is up to date:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable(
  UserID int not null,
  Weekenddate date not null,
  FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES Table1(UserID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO newTable (UserID, Weekenddate) 
    (SELECT (UserID, Weekenddate) FROM Table2 WHERE Totaltimeworked > 0);
```

Or if you meant just for 1 specific week don't add the Weekenddate to newTable and modify query as

```
INSERT INTO newTable (UserID)
    (SELECT (UserID) FROM Table2 WHERE Totaltimeworked > 0
         AND Weekenddate = 'year-month-day');
```

Comment: how to write a select statement from the above two tables where i should get userid ,username and email(from table1) of the users who dint submit the timesheet for the particular weekenddate(datefield-specified in search field) in table2

Comment: `select UserID, Username, Email from Table1 join newTable on newTable.UserID = Table1.UserID where newTable.Weekenddate = 'year-month-day'